# What needs to happen to answer an Access-Challenge from FreeRADIUS (802.1x EAP-TLS on wired connection)?

Tags: freeradius

I have been trying to get a client (embedded linux) to connect to a secure network by wired 802.1x through an authentication server using EAP-TLS.

I have been testing using FreeRADIUS 3.0.21 and the default certificates generated by Freeradius, and have not been able to fully authenticate a client. The client is running wpa_supplicant 2.9. Both server and client have OpenSSL 1.1.1k

There may be some configuration option that I am missing on the Radius server side, but it appears that either the NAS or client is failing to reply to an Access-Challenge properly.
The TLS handshake to finishes successfully, but the Access-Request finishes without logging an explicit Reject. I read somewhere that any Access-Challenge that is not responded to must be rejected. And that appears to be the case.

Relevant end of the log:

```
(17) Sent Access-Challenge Id 56 from 192.168.1.100:1812 to 192.168.1.29:49156 length 0
(17)   EAP-Message = 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
(17)   Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
(17)   State = 0xd616f039d502fd5e68d302f0d31f9724
(17) Finished request
```

I'm not sure what the client needs to do to answer this Challenge. Any ideas?

wpa_supplicant command and configuration:

`wpa_supplicant -dd -c /etc/wpa_sup_wired.conf -D wired -i eth0`

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
eapol_version=2
ap_scan=0

 network={
    ssid="wired"
    key_mgmt=IEEE8021X
    eap=TLS
    identity="testing"
    ca_cert="/home/root/test/ca.pem"
    client_cert="/home/root/test/client.crt"
    private_key="/home/root/test/client.key"
    private_key_passwd="whatever"
    eapol_flags=0
}
```

Comment: This is looking like it might be a hardware issue with the managed switch

Comment: The first switch I was using was a Linksys, a new Cisco SG350-10 is working.